Angular 17 refuses to instance component
I cannt reproduce it with anything, and I'm completely out of explanations for why it coudl be happening... I have the following component (with sideElementIs3d set to true, so it shows the threes-js app):
<div>
   <img src="assets/img/thumb/square.jpg" alt="">
   <div *ngIf="!sideElementIs3d" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':' url(assets/img/right.png)'}">
   </div>
   <app-three-js-interactive *ngIf="sideElementIs3d"></app-three-js-interactive>
</div>

And the app-three-js-interactive component:
<canvas #canvas></canvas>

I have spent roughly 5 hours now, trying to figure out why the app-three-js-interactive is not created, and my HTML inspector just looks like this with absolutely nothing inside the component. No constructor call, no ngInit, no ngAfterViewInit, nothing...

Even after removing all the code from the component it still does not instantiate anything

@Component({
  selector: 'app-three-js-interactive',
  templateUrl: './three-js-interactive.component.html'
})
export class ThreeJsInteractiveComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() scene!: THREE.Scene;

  @ViewChild('canvas', { static: false }) canvasRef!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  dog!: AnimationController;

  constructor(private canvasParentRef: ElementRef, private threeService: ThreejsProviderService) { 
    console.log("help!")
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log("help!")
  }

The module is declared in the app.module.ts and I've done everything I can think of to get it working but I am completely out of ideas, if I make a new component it works just fine, but this one component just does not want to be created in the place I am trying. It does work in a different location which is puzzling me even more... Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or any other info you need to help me figure out what is going on...

Can you provide the stackblitz, please?  https://stackblitz.com/

I definitely can https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/torbenvanassche/portfolio-project I just loaded my entire project in there since I don't know exactly what is going wrong with it... I do know I need to refactor the threeJsService to use multiple instances at the same time but I am using this project to learn angular on a small scale so I can do things properly when they matter.

Have you imported the module in which ThreeJsInteractiveComponent is declared?

@Chrillewoodz something so simple, yet I didn't notice. The sidebar I had which wasn't loading it was marked as standalone, however, I was not importing tthe threejscomponent in that standalone component because I didn't know I had to. it was in the app.module, but not in the standalone module...

Every time you have a component whose content isn't showing up this is the problem. It's sad that Angular doesn't actually warn you about this but what can you do eh.

As mentioned in the comment, ThreeJsInteractiveComponent (or the module which declares it) must be imported into the implementing standalone component for its content to show up:
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  ...
  template: `<app-three-js-interactive />`,
  imports: [
    ThreeJsInteractiveComponent
  ]
})
export class MyComponent {}

